# Delete TinyMCE texts

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I would like to know how to delete all the texts in the TinyMCE editor after clicking a button.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=10203

Comment: Please [provide context for links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Your answer should make sense on its own, even for readers who don't follow the link. It's fine to provide a summary in your answer and include the link for more information.